# jQuery selector to handle click function inside a loop result

Tags: javascript, jquery

Sorry for asking this again but code won't execute. The problem is that I have a php loop that produces a html like below

```
<a class="js-delete-comment1" data-url="http://localhost/project/document_items/delete_item_comment/1">link</a>
<a class="js-delete-comment2" data-url="http://localhost/project/document_items/delete_item_comment/2">link</a>
<a class="js-delete-comment3" data-url="http://localhost/project/document_items/delete_item_comment/3">link</a>
```

Now, I want to select specific class to use as a jQuery selector but won't work. See below code

```
$("[id*=js-delete-comment]").each(function(){
    $(this).click(function(){

    var url = $('.js-delete-comment').attr('data-url');
    // var id  = $('.js-delete-comment').attr('data-id');
    $.ajax({
      url       : url,
      type      : 'POST',
      dataType  : 'json',
      success   : function(result) {
        console.log(result);
      }
    });
    });
  });
```

Any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: var url = $(this).attr('data-url'); or var url = $('.js-delete-comment').data('url');

Comment: `data-*` in the markup is not included here I'll update the post now

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no ID on the elements, use `class^=` selector. There is no need of iterating over the elements and then bind the event, the event can be bind directly on the selector itself.

```
$("[class^='js-delete-comment']").click(function() {
```

Also, use `$(this).data('url')` to get the `data-url` attribute of the element that is clicked.

**Code:**

```
$("[class^='js-delete-comment']").click(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault(); // To stop page redirection

    var url = $(this).data('url');

    $.ajax({
        url: url,
        type: 'POST',
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function (result) {
            console.log(result);
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: Also mention that there is no `data-*` attribute in markup..`e.preventDefault()` will be needed as well ;)..+1

Comment: @Rayon Thanks, missed the `preventD` part.

Comment: Thanks, it's working now. and thanks also for specifying `$(this).data('url')`

Answer (score 1):

Just use click event like this:

```
$("[class^=js-delete-comment]").click(function(){

    var url = $(this).attr('data-url');
    $.ajax({
      url       : url,
      type      : 'POST',
      dataType  : 'json',
      success   : function(result) {
        console.log(result);
      }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use,

```
$("[class^=js-delete-comment]").click(function() {
  var url = $(this).data("url");
  $.ajax({
    url: url,
    type: 'POST',
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function(result) {
      console.log(result);
    }
  });
});
```

- `^` is the attribute starts with selector. you can use that for selecting the class
- Use data() method for getting the data-url

Answer (score 1):

I am not getting why you want to select these `<a>` links using class name.
Just put your code inside parent `<div>`

```
  <div id="js-delete-comment"> 
       <a class="js-delete-comment1" data-url="http://localhost/project/document_items/delete_item_comment/1">link</a>
       <a class="js-delete-comment2" data-url="http://localhost/project/document_items/delete_item_comment/2">link</a>
       <a class="js-delete-comment3" data-url="http://localhost/project/document_items/delete_item_comment/3">link</a>
 </div>
```

And your JQuery code will be

```
    $('#js-delete-comment > a').click(function(){
    $.ajax({
      url       : $(this).data('url'),
      type      : 'POST',
      dataType  : 'json',
      success   : function(result) {
        console.log(result);
      }
    }); 
  });
```